# The potential risks of using latest when updating dependencies

Tags: node.js, dependency-management

I'm using Yarn to manage my project's dependencies and have questions about updating them using *wanted* and *latest* versions. I know that *wanted* refers to the highest compatible version based on package.json, while *latest* is the most recent version available.

Why isn't using the latest version always the best option for updating dependencies, and what potential risks are involved?

For example, when I run `yarn outdated`, I get a table with the following columns:

- Package: The package name
- Current: The currently installed version
- Wanted: The highest compatible version based on my package.json
- Latest: The most recent version available

If I use `yarn upgrade` without the --latest flag, it will update my dependencies to the wanted versions.

However, if I use yarn upgrade --latest, it will update my dependencies to the latest versions and change the versioning requirements in my package.json file.

Could you explain the potential risks and best practices when updating dependencies using wanted vs. latest versions in Yarn? Any examples or use cases would be helpful!
I read many documentations, manuals etc. but I do not find a reference which clearly explains the potential problems when using latest.

Answer (score -2):

The wanted version keeps you on your current Major Version.
The latest version could update to a newer Major Version, which probably has Breaking Changes.

There are many examples in the real world. When you using Bootstrap4 (UI Framework) and update to the latest (Bootstrap5), some parts of your website will not work anymore.

But also a minor / patch version could break your current state. Mostly Developers will use the [semversion](https://semver.org/) to tell others what type of changes they can expect. NPM and Yarn are using it too for their outdated command :)